# How to access individual value of a map in a Map[String,(String, String)]

Tags: scala

How can i access the individual `values` in a Map, so to say. the Map is of type `Map[String,(String, String)]`. Based on the input string i want to return `value(String1)` or  `value(String2)` if the argument  matches key or to return the argument itself in case there is no match ,

```
val mappeddata = Map("LOWES" -> ("Lowes1","Lowes2"))
```

**Updated.**
the below is working in case when none of the values are empty

```
scala> mappeddata.find(_._1 == "LOWES").map(_._2._2).getOrElse("LOWES")
res135: Option[String] = Some(Lowes2)

scala> mappeddata.find(_._1 == "LOWES").map(_._2._1).getOrElse("LOWES")
res136: Option[String] = Some(Lowes1)
```

but if the value is empty that i want to return input string itself but instead its returning null

```
scala> val mappeddata = Map("LOWES" -> ("Lowes1",""))
mappeddata: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,(String, String)] = Map(LOWES -> (Lowes1,""))

scala> mappeddata.find(_._1 == "LOWES").map(_._2._2).getOrElse("LOWES")
res140: String = "
```

what needs to be done to fix this?

Comment: Please provide proper input and expected output

Comment: Updated.`LOWES` is the input string and the map contains `LOWES -> (Lowes1,Lowes2)`

Comment: @ChaitanyaWaikar if you believe i have improved the question, please upvote it

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are asking to get the values part of a Map. In my below example, I am extracting Lowes2.

```
val m = Map("LOWES" -> ("Lowes1","Lowes2"),  "Other" -> ("other1","other2"))
println(m.get("LOWES").get._1)  // will print **Lowes2**
```

Comment: Yes, but in case the value is null it should return the input string

Comment: I hope it will return empty string(as you gave empty string above) not null is n't it?

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
scala>  if (mappeddata.get("LOWES").get._1.isEmpty) "LOWES" else mappeddata.get("LOWES").get._1
res163: String = Lowes1

scala> if (mappeddata.get("LOWES").get._2.isEmpty) "LOWES" else mappeddata.get("LOWES").get._2
res164: String = LOWES
```

//**Updated**

```
 scala>  if (mappeddata("LOWES")._1.isEmpty) "LOWES" else mappeddata("LOWES")._1
    res163: String = Lowes1

    scala> if (mappeddata("LOWES")._2.isEmpty) "LOWES" else mappeddata("LOWES")._2
    res164: String = LOWES
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want but maybe this is helpful:

```
val m = Map[String, (String, String)]() 
val value = m("first") // value if exists or throws exception
val value: Option[(String, String)] = m.get("first")// as an option 
val values: List[(String, String)] = m.map(_._2).toList // list of values
```